# Shooting Method for coefficient matching in holography

Tags: computational-physics, boundary-conditions, ads-cft, condensation

Usually when one is attempting to solve the equations of motion of a bulk field in the AdS/CFT framework the main goal is to understand if a corresponding boundary operator aqcuires a VEV (commonly refered to as "Operator condensation" in the literature). However most of the equations cannot be solved anallyticaly and one is led to the use of numerical methods.

Most commonly one is led to a boundary value problem, where the behaviour of the solution is known near two boundary points. For example consider a problem defined for $z\in [0,1]$ and the Frobenius expansions being $$R(z)=z^\Delta(c_0+\sum_n a_n z^n)$$ near z=0 and $$R(z)=c_1+\sum_n b_n (z-1)^n$$ near z=1.

I am interested in learning more about the use of shooting techniques for matching the coefficients of the two series while adjusting the parameter $c_0$. The goal here is to see if by starting from the first solution we can recover the second at some intermediate point by adjusting the coefficient $c_0$. Anyone knows how this can be done in detail?